# Codenameone error while building on the server

Tags: codenameone

i am having these error log while trying to build in codenameone, compilation is with success, but on the server i have these error log

see attached file
[error log](https://codename-one.appspot.com/getData?m=result&i=4784142220001280&b=9aa85d16-4b3e-4619-b359-40d5c6fb1732&n=error.txt)

Here is my build hints tab image:

[image]

How can i fix that?

here is the [new error](https://codename-one.appspot.com/getData?m=result&i=4593316621713408&b=e83ebcc1-dac8-413c-a09d-9c283688ce4a&n=error.txt) log after some arrangement

Comment: Are you sending a versioned build? Any special `android.*` build hints?

Comment: What do you mean by versioned build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the build hint `android.gradle=false` I suggest removing that.

The old Ant based build pipeline is deprecated by Google and is unmaintained, some things might fail there.